# Why does java.lang.VerifyError mean?

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy, verifyerror

While I've tried to use the following code snippet with the Groovy **in-operator** explanation the **VerifyError** has occured. Have you guys any idea about?

The code and console output is below.

```
class Hello extends ArrayList {
    boolean isCase(Object val) {
        return val == 66
    }

    static void main(args) {
        def myList = new Hello()
        myList << 55
        assert 66 in myList
        assert !myList.contains(66)
    }
}
```

The error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Hello, method: super$1$stream signature: ()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

The code origin from the topic [How does the Groovy in operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068298/how-does-the-groovy-in-operator-work#answer-2068393).

**Update**:

Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.6.0_45 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux

Comment: It means the generated bytecode is invalid. What version of Groovy? It works fine for me from groovyConsole.

Comment: @DaveNewton Groovy version is 1.8.6

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.
It's for Java, but generally problem is, that you are using wrong library versions. The class is there, but different version than expected.

http://craftingjava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/3-reasons-for-javalangverfiyerror.html

Probably you have messed up Groovy or Java SDK installations.

Comment: The individual installations are likely okay, it's more likely to be a classpath or Groovy compilation issue.