# In operation on String gives false

Tags: string, groovy, contains

I was trying to see whether a string contains a character in groovy.
Following code returns `false`

```
print "a" in "apple"
```

and following code returns `true`

```
print "apple".cointains("a")
```

I tried the same with list/array, In that case both code returns true,

```
def a=[1,2,3]
print 1 in a //prints true
print a.contains(1)//prints true
```

Why `in`  didn't work in string ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068298/how-does-the-groovy-in-operator-work

Comment: Thank you daggett. Shared link explains what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *in* operator depends on the *isCase* method.
For a *string* object, *isCase* only does an *equals*-check.

Try to overwrite the *isCase* method in your case.

See [DefaultGroovyMethods](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java) for default *isCase* implementation.